# scipy.interpolate interp2d is deprecated

Tags: scipy, 2d, interpolation

To be able to interpolate a simple 2D pandas grid
I extracted the index and columns and casted the DataFrame to a numpy array

Then assign a function as follows f=scipy.interp2d(x_index,y_index,my2Ddata)
Where x_index and y_index are 1 dimensional numpy array and my2Ddata the numpy data array
Then just called the function f(a,b) which returns the interpolated value

But how can I do this now the `interp2d` is deprecated?

from the error message in Jupyter note book (ref below) I cannot find a simple solution

What is now the most effective and simplest form of doing what I want to do?

---

Error message:

For legacy code, nearly bug-for-bug compatible replacements are
`RectBivariateSpline` on regular grids, and `bisplrep`/`bisplev` for
scattered 2D data.

In new code, for regular grids use `RegularGridInterpolator` instead.
For scattered data, prefer `LinearNDInterpolator` or
`CloughTocher2DInterpolator`.

For more details see

Comment: "It also contains recommendations for what to use instead of `interp2d`" , from [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10268#issuecomment-1304752037). The link that is referencing has examples with code. See section 2 [there](https://gist.github.com/ev-br/8544371b40f414b7eaf3fe6217209bff) , that says 'For new code, the recommended alternative is RegularGridInterpolator. It is an independent implementation, not based on FITPACK. Supports nearest, linear interpolation and odd-order tensor product splines."

Comment: you are mostly looking for `RegularGridInterpolator((x_index,y_index), my2Ddata)`.